# Why are AWS web applications' front and backends directly connected in these diagrams?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment

In multiple AWS architecture diagrams for web applications, I am seeing that the backend is typically connected directly (via load balancer) to the webserver. Here are some links to diagrams that show this connection.

https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:1400/format:webp/1*PDHya_zt_n657nYUAm1OeA.jpeg

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/web-application-hosting-best-practices/an-aws-cloud-architecture-for-web-hosting.html

This connection doesn't make sense to me as it insinuates that the webserver itself will make requests to the backend. However, my understanding is that the execution flow will be

1. the webserver will serve the webpage to the client, and
2. within that client (browser), code will be executed and the backend endpoint will be triggered

Therefore, it makes more sense to me that since the request to the backend endpoint comes from the browser and not by the webserver, both the backend and frontend should be attached to that initial load balancer. Attached is an diagram of my proposed architecture.

[my proposed architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19IQm.png)

I assume their architectures are correct -- what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, all three diagrams are correct. In your proposed architecture the ALB would be considered the frontend and your "Frontend" and "Backend" could be considered two backends. One serving the static HTML/JS/... while the "Backend" would act more like a traditional backend (handling dynamic API calls).

The term "frontend" is vague, IMHO, and its functionality is not strict. Traditionally we think of something that serves the HTML/JS/... and forwards all other requests to the backend to be fulfilled. It may also be used for caching or authentication. Therefore also fulfilling things we would also call a reverse proxy. This is tied to the fact what functionalities were implemented in software for the "frontend" (usually nginx, apache, ...).

If this doesn't make sense so far, follow me to the HTTP level: You need a distinctive factor on what to serve on every HTTP request. Make this the URL, for example. Something needs to decide what to serve given the URL. Usually this entity is called the "frontend".
If the "frontend" decides that the URL is static content, traditionally it handles the request itself as the software for this can do this easily (nginx, apache, etc.). If it is dynamic content it needs to outsource or forward the request something else, called a "backend".

AWS must separate things to sell their Software or to teach how their building blocks make sense. So an ALB can be used as frontend with its functionionaly, but also EC2 instances. CloudFront can also function as a frontend. Etc.